# Las tablas generadas por FastAPI no están relacionadas, cuando las veo en el workbench

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Estoy haciendo una API usando FastAPI.

Lo primero que hice fue modelar mi base de datos en el programa de workbench
y quedó de la siguiente manera con sus respectivas relaciones

[image: MODELO DE LA BASE DE DATOS]

Lo segundo que hice, fue realizar los modelos en FastAPI y quedaron de la siguiente manera:

```
    # coding: utf-8
from sqlalchemy import CHAR, Column, ForeignKey, JSON, String, TIMESTAMP, text
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import BIT, INTEGER, TINYINT
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata


class FarmType(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'farm_types'

    frm_type_id = Column(TINYINT, primary_key=True)
    frm_type_name = Column(String(45), nullable=False)
    frm_type_created = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False, server_default=text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))
    frm_type_enabled = Column(BIT(2), nullable=False)


class Region(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'regions'

    reg_id = Column(TINYINT, primary_key=True)
    reg_name = Column(String(45), nullable=False)
    reg_created = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False, server_default=text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))
    reg_updated = Column(TIMESTAMP)
    reg_enabled = Column(BIT(2))


class Farm(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'farms'

    frm_id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    frm_name = Column(String(45), nullable=False)
    frm_restriction = Column(JSON)
    frm_created = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False, server_default=text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))
    frm_updated = Column(TIMESTAMP)
    frm_enabled = Column(BIT(2), nullable=False)
    REGION_frm_id = Column(ForeignKey('regions.reg_id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False, index=True)
    FARM_TYPES_frm_id = Column(ForeignKey('farm_types.frm_type_id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False, index=True)

    FARM_TYPES_frm = relationship('FarmType')
    REGION_frm = relationship('Region')


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    usr_id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    usr_username = Column(String(45), nullable=False)
    usr_password = Column(CHAR(32))
    user_name = Column(String(45))
    usr_lastname = Column(String(45))
    usr_created = Column(TIMESTAMP)
    usr_updated = Column(TIMESTAMP)
    REGION_usr_id = Column(ForeignKey('regions.reg_id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False, index=True)

    REGION_usr = relationship('Region')


class FarmsVisited(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'farms_visited'

    frm_visited_id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    frm_visited_date = Column(TIMESTAMP, server_default=text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))
    FARM_frm_visited_id = Column(ForeignKey('farms.frm_id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False, index=True)
    USER_frm_visited_id = Column(ForeignKey('users.usr_id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False, index=True)

    FARM_frm_visited = relationship('Farm')
    USER_frm_visited = relationship('User')
```

Lo tercero que hice fue revisar las tablas que me generó FastAPI y en workbench hice un "reverse enginer" para ver como quedó el modelo, y mi sorpresa fue que no tenía las relaciones..
como se muestra en la siguiente Imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las relaciones se hacen con llaves foráneas y no veo que hayas especificado ninguna

Comment: Dejame actualizarlo

Answer (score 0):

en la linea donde declare el foreingkey
solo con el tipo de dato y la llave foranea es suficiente, como se muestra en el ejemplo

REGION_usr_id =Column(Integer,ForeignKey('regions.reg_id')

y para la relacion entre tablas te hace falta el punto de relacion, en tu codigo solo esta referenciando la clase, pero le hace falta el punto de comunicacion

asi estaba en el codigo anterior -
REGION_usr = relationship('Region')

como deberia de ser -

class User(Base):
**tablename** = 'users'

```
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
name = Column(String(65), nullable=False)
email = Column(String(65), unique=True, nullable=True)
avatar = Column(String(45), nullable=False)
pasword = Column(String(45), nullable=False)
dateCreate = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False)
status = Column(Boolean, default=True)

organization_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('organizations_users.id'))
role_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('roles.id'))

organization_user = relationship('Organization_User', back_populates='user')
```

> information = relationship('Information', back_populates='user')
> en la tabla users utiliza relationship para comunicar las tablas, el primer parametro es la clase con el que se quiere comunicar, en el segundo parametro seleccionas el punto de encuntro

```
role = relationship('Role', back_populates='user')
```

class Information(Base):
**tablename** = 'informations'

```
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
document_number = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
phone_number = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
address = Column(String(45), nullable=False)
occupation = Column(String(45), nullable=False)
dateCreate = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False)
dateUpdate = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=True)

user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
document_type_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('documents_types.id'))
```

> user = relationship('User', back_populates='information')
> al igual se hace en la otra tabla, se utiliza este proceso para comunicar las dos tablas entre si

```
document_type = relationship('DocumentType', back_populates='information')
```